# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:4

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I will get MethodNotAllowedHttpException when submitting a form in laravel

Html file

```
<form method="POST" action="/cards/{{$card->id}}/notes">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
    <textarea name="body" class="form-control"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Add Note</button>
</form>
```

routes.php

```
Route::post('cards/{card}/notes','NotesController@store');
```

NotesController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class NotesController extends Controller
{
    public function store()
    {
        return request()->all();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show generated html code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you don't have a route, say a `Route::post` with a parameter that lies in front of the route you are trying to hit.

For example:

```
Route::post('{something}', 'SomethingController@index');
Route::post('cards/{card}/notes', 'NotesController@store');
```

In this case, no matter what you try to send to the cards route, it will always hit the `something`  route because `{something}` is intercepting `cards` as a valid parameter and triggers the `SomethingController`.
Put the `something` route below the cards route and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is thrown when no matching route (method and URI) was found, but a route with a matching URI but not matching method was found.

In your case, I guess the issue is because URI parameters differ between the route and the controller.

Here are two alternatives you can try:

1. Remove the parameter from your route:

```
Route::post('cards/notes','NotesController@store');
```

2. Add the parameter to your controller:

```
    public function store($card)
    {
        return request()->all();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, both solutions are working fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve this error in lumen and it took me quite a lot of time to figure out the problem.
The problem is with laravel itself.

> Sometimes if you have another route like GET device/{variable}, laravel stops in this first route...

So what you need to do is change the route `POST device` to `POST device/add`

[This link helped me a lot](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-methodnotallowedhttpexception?page=1)